# 'ModuleNotFoundError' on local editor but not in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to use Python's *requests* module, so I installed it using

`pip install requests`,

then it appears that *requirement is already satisfied* in Miniconda library. On my script, I import request as

`import requests`,

and when I run the script I get ModuleNotFoundError. However, if I do the same thing in Jupyter, the module works and no error appears. What should I do to use that module locally in my editor?

Comment: Did you [activate](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) conda using - `conda activate myenv` before running the script?

Comment: Tried running the script under base environment and I get the same error.

Comment: It looks like you are using python3 in your local editor. Install library usung pip3 install requests

Comment: It worked! Thank you